# JSP Pages on IIS7

Tags: jsp, iis-7

I am currently trying to configure JSP pages on my webserver. I have followed the instructions of installing TomCat and JDK and JRE and add Handler Mappings to the isapi_redirect.dll in the tomcat directory.

I have restarted the IIS server however it keeps on coming up with an error

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found The
>   requested content appears to be script
>   and will not be served by the static
>   file handler.

If anyone can help with this problem it will be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you are using .NET environment
http://www.gtrifonov.com/2009/02/27/iis-7-http-error-404-17-the-requested-content-appears-to-be-script/